# Icon not updated from setState() function even tho build() is called

Tags: flutter, setstate

I try to update a Containers variable (eventInfo.addedToCalendar stored in ValueKey) to determine which Icon should be displayed. The value seems to be updated correctly and the stateful Widget's build function gets called but no change is visible. Only after resizing the window the new Icon is displayed.

I have List in my StatefulWidget holding all Containers:

```
List<Container> allEvents = [];
```

And get the Containers (Events) from initState() via:

```
fetchEvents(guiAddToCalendar).then((events) => {
      setState(() {
        allEvents.addAll(events);
      }),
    });
```

While I give each Container a reference to my guiAddToCalendar() function to update the corresponding Container:

```
guiAddToCalendar(int eventId, bool added) {
  for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++) {
    Container eventContainer = allEvents[i];
    ValueKey<Event> eventKey = eventContainer.key as ValueKey<Event>;
    Event eventInfo = eventKey.value;

    if (eventInfo.id == eventId) {
      setState(() {
        eventInfo.addedToCalendar = added;
        print(" eventInfo.addedToCalendar changed to $added");
      });
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The actual Container has an Event Class with all variables

```
final eventInfo = Event(
  dataID,
  dataName,
  ...
  addedToCalendar: false);



Container container = Container(
    key: ValueKey(eventInfo),
...

IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      eventInfo.addedToCalendar
                          ? FeezIcons.star_full
                          : FeezIcons.star_full_border,
                      shadows: const <Shadow>[
                        Shadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 10.0),
                        Shadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 2.0)
                      ],
                      size: 30,
                      color: cols.colAcent0,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      bool addedToCalendar = await addToCalendar(dataID);
                      addToCalendarCallback(eventInfo.id, addedToCalendar);
                    },
                  ),
...
)
```

The build function looks like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: allEvents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return allEvents[index];
                    },
                  ),
...
}
```

Comment: i am missing the fetchEvents functions, its key to understand the whole picture bro

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve the issue by refactoring the Container Widget to a Stateful Widget and call its own setState() function.